# Suggestion to improve performance of a piece of c# code

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

We are developing a highly realtime application. The application isn't performing up to the mark. We did some performance profiling and found following piece of code takes most of the time

```
for (int i = 0; i < _chunkSize; i++)
{
   outputData[i] = (byte)(inputText[i] ^ nonce[i % NonceSize]);
}
```

Where `_chunkSize` is `1024000` and `NonceSize` is `16`. The variables `inputText`, `outputData` and `nonce` are `byte` arrays.

Please suggest changes to this snippet to improve performance

**EDit**

To give more context -

I have a developed my own DRM system where I use a custom .NET implementation of CTR encryption algorithm. While the movie is being played, 1 MB chunks of the movie are read from a encrypted media file, decrypted in memory and fed to the player. The decryption runs slowly and hence the player fails to play the movie of larger size (>300MB). The nonce in the above piece of code is calculated at runtime for every encrypted 1 MB chunk and XORed with the chunk to decrypt it.

Comment: Without more informations about what you're doing here it's difficult to suggest different, more efficient approaches.

Comment: You'll need better hardware.  DDR4 is nice.

Comment: It's `_chunkSize` that's the killer - 1,024,000 iterations through a loop.  The loop's body can be quick, but that will still be where you spend a lot of time: optimizing the loop's body will yield less than figuring out whether/how you can reduce `_chunkSize`.

Comment: Can you change it to `int` or `long` array to process 4 or 8 bytes at a time?

Comment: What's the *content* of your code? You can't do optimizations right unless you see the big picture. A dead-simple suggestion could be 'process `long`s instead of `byte`s to make use of your CPUs bandwidth'. However, that leads to nowhere unless you disclose the algorithm as a whole, plus what are your *current* performance results, and what's the goal (and why).

Comment: …not *content* but *context*… sorry for the typo.

Comment: Do you think moving the for into a Parallel.For will give significant improvement? The loop runs 64000 times doing a simple compute operation.

Comment: @Kartik I misread your comment. Yes, running the loop inside  a `Parallel.For` *might* help, try it and let us know how it goes.

Comment: So I ran ANTS performance profiler with original code, with dcastro's suggestion and with parallel.for and I found that for hit count of 1616 for the method that wraps this code, following were the time in seconds - 42.372, 48.742 and 68.086. SO it seems the original code is the fastest.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid using the remainder operator to keep the index in the `[0, NonceSize[` range, and do that manually instead.

```
int index = 0;
for (int i = index; i < _chunkSize; i++, index++)
{
    if(index == NonceSize)
        index = 0;
    outputData[i] = (byte)(inputText[i] ^ nonce[index]);
}
```

That might help a bit.

---

I increased the `_chunkSize` to 102400000, to make the results more relevant.

With the remainder operator

```
1431 1411 1445 1368 1312 1427 1436 1265 1102 1077
Average: 1327.4
```

Without

```
1133 1197 1122 973 976 1032 1460 1229 1211 1145
Average: 1147.8
```

Without the remainder operator, the loop was 13.6% faster.

Comment: Any *specific* measured improvements?

Comment: @OndrejTucny I've added some numbers